# InputAccessoryView is not visible on iOS 13

Tags: ios, ios13, uitoolbar, inputaccessoryview, inputview

In ViewController I've added InputButton. I have custom class for picking value from input view.

```
class InputButton: UIButton {
    var customInputView: UIView = UIView()
    var customInputAccessoryView: UIView = UIView()

    override var inputView: UIView {
        get { return self.customInputView }
        set { self.customInputView = newValue }
    }
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
        get { return self.customInputAccessoryView }
        set { self.customInputAccessoryView = newValue }
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return self.isEnabled
    } 
}
```

After I tap the button, I perform (in ViewController):

```
self.currencyButton.inputView = self.currenciesPicker
self.currencyButton.inputAccessoryView = self.doneToolbar
self.currencyButton.becomeFirstResponder()
```

**doneToolbar** is custom UIToolbar with set

```
private lazy var spaceItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
    let item: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    return item
}()
private lazy var doneItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
    let item: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.doneButton)
    return item
}()

...

self.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
self.items = [
    self.spaceItem,
    self.doneItem
]
```

Size is set manually but I also tried to set it with different way.

[this is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG1mx.jpg)

I don't know why on iOS 13 inputAccessoryView **is not** visible but on iOS 12 it displays properly

In [**debug view hierarchy**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9oUI.jpg) inputAccessoryView looks just fine